# What happens when you put a Portable Hole inside a Bag of Holding while on the Astral plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, planes

What would happen if someone were to place a Portable Hole within a Bag of Holding while being within the Astral Plane? Would it be the reverse effect?

Comment: Congratulations, I think you may have found the furthest possible thing from the intended use of either of these items. It's people like you who keep IT people like me busy. ;)

Comment: As aftermath of your action you will encounter CR 900 DM Fiat

Comment: I would question whether you could even take a portable hole to the Astral Plane.  Any means I can think of to get it there would also be in danger of creating an extra-dimensional rift (or just not working).

Comment: @RBarryYoung Plane Shift?

Answer (score 70):

According to the description it would still create a gate to a random location on the Astral Plane.

> Placing a portable hole inside an extradimensional
> space created by a bag of holding [...] instantly destroys both items and
> opens a gate to the Astral Plane. **The gate originates
> where the one item was placed inside the other.** Any
> creature within 10 feet of the gate is sucked through it
> **to a random location on the Astral Plane**. The gate then
> closes. The gate is **one-way only** and can't be reopened.

It would be a Gate from one location in the Astral Plane to another.